# VisualStudioCode - how to enable current cursor position

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I enable this view? To show current cursor position (line, column) and number of selected characters? I think I've checked all possible values in the settings, yet I still do not know where to find it.

[image: vsc_cursor_position]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't see the position and selection count, it is probably the case that you have too much items in the status bar. Disable the ones are not relevant to you by right clicking on the status bar:

[image: Status bar options]

Also if you don't use your entire screen width, they also disappear if there isn't enough real-estate. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to set priority to the items.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps

View -> Appearance -> Show Status Bar

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I do have status bar enabled, I got opened files in editor, but the whole bottom is blue. No number/letters, nothing. I guess I'll reinstall it soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the functionality you ask about was added quite recently. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60537#issuecomment-660066544) it is said that "line number and column number are shown in version 1.46, May 2020. On selection, they disappear."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Editor Selection" is checked after opening the Status Bar options.

[image]